# insert current time into table

Tags: java, oracle, date, time

```
                java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
                java.sql.Date today = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime()); //2012-03-23
                java.sql.Time time = new java.sql.Time(date.getTime()); //02:32:46
                PreparedStatement pst = null;
String queryString = "INSERT INTO PR_VISITOR(PRISONER_ID,VISITOR_NAME,FATHER_NAME,DOV,IN_TIME) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
                        pst = connect.prepareStatement(queryString);
                        pst.setString(1, pr_id);
                        pst.setString(2, visit);
                        pst.setString(3, father);
                        pst.setDate(4, today);
                        pst.setTime(5, time);
                        int officerQuery = pst.executeUpdate();
                        if (officerQuery == 1) {
                            response.sendRedirect("/FYP3.4/prisonAdmin/visitor_out.jsp");
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Visitor information registered !!", "Visitor Information", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                        } else {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Unable to Add information !!", "Visitor Information", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                        }
```

By using the above code i'm trying to insert the current date and time into table,which have the separate columns. When i'm executing the above query then it insert the todays date in the time `IN_TIME` field too.

**EDIT**

DATATYPE OF `IN_TIME` and `DOV` are `DATE` .

Need Help.. !!

Comment: What is the type of the IN_TIME column?

Comment: SYSDATE will be the database way of declaring the current time.

Comment: @sql_query - What data types are the columns `DOV` and `IN_TIME` in your database?

Comment: Datatype of DOV is DATE and IN_TIME is also DATE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since DOV and IN_TIME is `date` you don't need to separate date and hour. The type `date` in Oracle holds date and time. I suggest you change your table to have just one date column.

To insert the current time you can use the Oracle's `sysdate` function:

```
INSERT INTO PR_VISITOR(PRISONER_ID,VISITOR_NAME,FATHER_NAME,DATETIME_COLUMN) VALUES (?,?,?,?,SYSDATE)
```

To format your output of the date value you can use the `SimpleDateFormat` class in Java or `to_char` in Oracle.

Comment: in this case, what would be the datatype of the `DATETIME_COLUMN`

Answer (score 1):

A `DATE` column in an Oracle database will always store both a day (i.e. March 22, 2012) and a time to the second (i.e. 3:30:00 PM).  A java.sql.Date and a java.sql.Time store the day and time as well but to the millisecond.

It doesn't really make sense to have separate columns in Oracle for the day and for the time but particularly not where both columns are declared as `DATE` data types.  It would be much more conventional to use a single column declared as a `DATE`.  If you really wanted to, you could truncate the day so that it represents midnight on the current day and then store the time component as, say, an `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND`.  But that would generally add a fair amount of complexity to the system for very little gain.

Answer (score 0):

You're much better off using oracle's 'systimestamp'.  The reason being, if you're java code is running in one timezone, and oracle lives in another.  Forcing your own Time object, could cause problems.

Do you really need separate fields for this?  I would think just having a timestamp would be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). This is one way I have used it:

```
Date now = Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
String date = df.format(now);
DateFormat tf = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmmss");
String time = tf.format(now);
```

Comment: how..??

i was trying like this..

`SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
                java.util.Date birth = (java.util.Date) dateFormat.parse(date.toString());
                java.sql.Date db = new java.sql.Date(birth.getTime());`

Answer (score 0):

Follow this,it will help both in java and oracle

create table datetime(date_time timestamp);

insert into datetime values (sysdate);

To get date:
select to_char(date_time,'DD-MON-YY') from datetime;

eg:12-JUL-12

To get month:
select to_char(date_time,'mm') from datetime;

eg:7

To get time:
select to_char(date_time,'HH24:MI:SS') from datetime;

eg:23:56:15

cheers!!